# App fonts/images are zoomed after ios upgrade

Tags: ios

I upgraded ios version to 9.3.5 some time back. After that my App fonts and images are zoomed in. Please help how to get it back to original. I have tried everything in the settings, nothing is changed there.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general cellphone tech support.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my question. I wanted to know what changes I need to do in my XCode application so that the font size does not get affected. I see that other applications are not affected so there is something I am not doing in my application. Please help.